# File Transfer in datanodes - hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

To `transfer` the files to datanodes what protocol hadoop uses?

```
SSH or http or https
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess TCP is the answer you want. The server is [DataXceiverServer](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-hdfs/2.0.0-cdh4.3.0/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/datanode/DataXceiverServer.java?av=f) and the client is [DFSClient](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-hdfs/2.0.0-cdh4.3.0/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/DFSClient.java#DFSClient). Basiclly, they use the Java Socket API.